# ArcPad 10 dependent fields

Tags: arcpad

Am trying to create an ArcPAD project when one entry with a specific value e.g.. Lamp post creates a mandatory field entry for material of the lamp post.

Comment: Is this edit on the same layer?  Mandatory field entry, is this to be user defined (by drop down) or hard coded?

Comment: Thanks it is on the same layer and it would be user defined by drop a down list. Am struggling to get it to work.

Comment: Please provide additional details (e.g. provide screen capture of edit form, what have you tried thus far (e.g. do you have any vb script for this action...etc)).

Comment: Thanks artwork21 for replying I found a help article which somehow I missed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this link has the answer to what I was looking for:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcpad/10.0/help/index.html#/Steps_to_explore_your_data/00s1000000vr000000/